# Getting all tweets of a specific twitter account?

Tags: objective-c

I just want to fetch all tweets of an specific twitter account. I want to use below url but don't know how we can get user_id or screen_name of a twitter account, whose tweets we want to fetch.

Resource URL http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.format Parameters Always specify either an user_id or screen_name when requesting a user timeline.

Does any one have any idea or source code or reference. Any help will be highly appreciable.

I am using following function for getting 200 tweets but it shows in NSLog

> HTTP response status: 403 message

Function

```
- (IBAction)followOnTwitter:(id)sender
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
            // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
                // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [tempDict setValue:@"rohit40793982" forKey:@"screen_name"];
                //[tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];
               // [tempDict setValue:@"683286" forKey:@"user_id "];

                TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.format"] 
                                                             parameters:tempDict 
                                                          requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];


                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",urlResponse);
                    tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                            options:kNilOptions 
                                                              error:&error];
                    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                    NSLog(@"%@", output);
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];

                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I am not receiving array of all tweets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake, I think, is with this line

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.format
```

the ".format" is the format you want the response. For example, if you want XML, use

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml
```

or for JSON, use

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

You will also need to append the screen_name as a query.  For example, to get all of my tweets as JSON, use

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=edent
```

Answer (score 1):

screen_name is basically, the account name. It's the name right after the '@'. Like WOW's screen_name is @Warcraft.

Oh and in fact the .format was the problem. You have to specify one of the 3: atom, json, or xml. (I think that getting the user timeline don't allow xml return, just read the API)

As I'm a Java programmer I'm afraid I can't help any further :/

Comment: Due to recent twitter changes, json is the only available format now: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#New_Twitter_client_policies